# Como buscar STRING dentro do JSON em Android

Tags: android, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON

**Cria_Pedido.txt**

```
 {"dados":[{
    "Cod_Produto":"25",
    "Produto":"ARROZ",
    "Quantidade":"200KG",
    "Estoque":"300KG",
    "Valor":"1200",
    "Num_pedido":"41045"}
    ]}
```

Criei um botão chamado "Buscar pedido" para receber o numero como parâmetro e verificar  se o "Num_pedido" existe ou não no `JSON`,como por exemplo digitar "41045" no `TextView` e ao clicar no botão realizar a busca ,mas não estou conseguindo obter nenhum retorno

**activity_cadastro**

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        android:text="BUSCAR PEDIDO"
        android:onClick="load"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="BUSCAR PEDIDO" />
```

Classe **Cadastro**

```
public class cadastro<textView> extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "Cria_Pedido.txt";

    TextView mEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);


    }


    public void criar(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, criar_pedido.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void adicionar(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, addproduto.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void load(View view) {
        // mEditText = findViewById(R.id.text);

         FileInputStream fis = null;
        //mEditText = findViewById(R.id.text);
     try {

        fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String text ="Num_pedido";

            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(text).append("\n");
            }

            mEditText.setText(sb.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Tente usar Gson (biblioteca do google) para converter o seu JSON em uma lista de objetos do tipo pedido (você precisa criar antes a classe Pedido) e então verificar se a lista tem um objeto cuja propriedade num_pedido corresponde à busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altera essa parte do seu código. Retira o text e faz assim:

```
while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(text);
}
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    mEditText.setText(jsonObject.getString("Num_pedido"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Você poderia jogar esse catch para junto do catch de IOException que já existe também.

Como já comentaram, seria interessante você dar uma olhada no GSON, ele poderia te ajudar nesse início. Tem um guia legal nesse link:  https://sites.google.com/site/aulasvictormenegusso/programacao-web-2-1-semestre-2017/trabalhando-com-json-com-a-biblioteca-gson